# php - replace part of string with a part of another string

Tags: php, string, str-replace

been searching all around for this and here is what I can't figure out.

I want to replace the bolded part of the following string:

/pano_virtual/public/admin/content/edit/2

if it matches to any part of the following string:

http://localhost/pano_virtual/public/

As you can see the **/pano_virtual/public/** part matches and if it does, I want to remove it from the first string.

I can't use a simle str_replace, because both strings will change with different servers and different websites, but this first part of the first will always match to the last part of the second string.

Is that possible?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT - SOLVED!:

I managed to figure it out but it's not the best solution, but it works:

```
// $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is the first string
// URL_ROOT is the second string

$url_root_substring = '';
$root_count = strlen(URL_ROOT);
$start = 0;
while($start < $root_count) {
    $substring = substr(URL_ROOT.'/',$start,$root_count);
    if($substring == substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,strlen($substring))) {
        $url_root_substring = $substring;
        break;
    }
    $start++;
}
```

Comment: "I  want to replace the bolded part of the following string..."  What bolded part?  Please format your question appropriately.

Comment: If there are multiple ways to match do you want the longest match? eg `/a/b/a/c` to `http://localhost/a/b/a/` could become either `http://localhost/a/b/a/b/a/c` or `http://localhost/a/b/a/c`.

Comment: So you want to remove the longest prefix of the first string that is also a suffix of the second string?

Comment: I'm sorry for bad formatting of the question. Yes, Jon, that is exactly what I need - how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)

Comment: So http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#PHP then...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to match *paths*, not strings.  I'm guessing you wouldn't want `http://host/foobar` to match `barcamp/whatever`.

So I would recommend splitting the strings on "/". Then it's just a matter of iterating over the "http" array looking for the first element from the "path" array.  If you find a match, advance to the second element, etc.  If two elements don't match, reset to the start of the "path" array.  If you get to the end of the "http" array and the last element matched, then you have your longest common path (if not, then there wasn't anything in common).

Answer (score 0):

```
$path_1 = '/pano_virtual/public/admin/content/edit/2';
$path_2 = 'http://localhost/pano_virtual/public/';
$pattern = '#^(https?:/)?/?([^/].*[^/])/?$#i';
preg_match($pattern, $path_1, $matches);
$clean_path_1 = $matches[2];
preg_match($pattern, $path_2, $matches);
$clean_path_2 = $matches[2];
$path_1_parts = explode('/', $clean_path_1);
$path_2_parts = explode('/', $clean_path_2);
$consider_path_2 = $path_2_parts;
$high_count = 0;
foreach($path_2_parts as $p2p)
{
  $consider_path_1 = $path_1_parts;
  foreach($path_1_parts as $p1p)
  {
    if($consider_path_1==$consider_path_2)
    {
      if(count($consider_path_1)>$high_count)
      {
        $high_count = count($consider_path_1);
        $best_match = implode('/', $consider_path_1);
      }
    }
    array_pop($consider_path_1);
  }
  array_shift($consider_path_2);
}
$answer = str_replace($best_match, '', $clean_path_1);
echo 'answer: '.$answer."\n";
```

output:

```
answer: /admin/content/edit/2
```